# Is it safe to call Dispose on an instance from event handler?

Tags: c#-4.0, idisposable

```
public class MyTask : IDisposable { ... }

MyTask task = new MyTask(() => SomeTask);

task.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    // do something with result
    ...
    // dispose of this instance
    ((MyTask)s).Dispose();
};

// execute the task
task.Execute();
```

Clearly I cannot tell when the task will be completed, so the only actual place, as I see it, that i can dispose of this instance is in Completed event.

Is this safe to do?

Comment: Is is necessary to dispose instances of `MyTask` ?

Comment: well, if it wasn't necessary, it would not implement IDisposable.

Comment: I'm sorry I worded that poorly. I Was just curious what you where doing that would require a manual dispose, as thats a fairly rare requirement.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by manually? Do you compare #using# vs calling Dispose()? #Using# can be used only for synchronous tasks, and I do not see having async tasks as "rare" requirement.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense.  If you expect the client code to dispose the object then why not just dispose yourself after raising the event?

Comment: @Hans Passant I have made a comment below on SuperCat's answer, where I made comparison to Task library, so maybe its more clearer what I need.

Comment: Well, you are trying to change the question.  The Task class is pretty broken, the author of the class [recommends to not dispose it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx).  But you don't want to talk about that either.

Comment: I am not trying to change the question, I pointed to TPL example in for all of you to understand my question better, since my class has very similar usage as Task from TPL. I said i do not want to talk about the issue should we dispose TPL Task, since I have already read the link you have provided, and I know all about it - it's conclusion - "not, unless..." and then he doesn't cover the "unless situation". If my class has similar usage as TPL Task, and if the client uses my class in a way to dispose it in completed event (similar to ContinueWith), is it safe to Dispose it like this or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, alas, no general rule as to when it is safe to call `Dispose`.  If Microsoft had specified that `Dispose` must be safe to call at any time when an object isn't in use, complying with such a rule would seldom have been difficult; in cases where a class might not always be able to perform all necessary cleanup immediately(*), it would generally be possible for it to set a flag and/or otherwise arrange to have necessary cleanup performed at the next opportunity.  Unfortunately, Microsoft does not specify that `Dispose` implementations have to handle asynchronous `Dispose` requests, nor is there any general way for an object which holds the last useful reference to an `IDisposable` instance to ask for notification when it would be safe to dispose.

Despite the general lack of assurance as to when it is safe to call Dispose, many particular classes which implement `Dispose` do offer guarantees as to when it may safely be called.  If one knows that a particular object is of a type which can be safely disposed in a particular context, one may dispose it then.  Especially in cases where an event from an object may be the only opportunity to `Dispose` it in a threading context it could know about, and where disposing an object within an event handler would make sense, it should be safe to dispose of the object.  Any properly-written event handlers should be prepared for the possibility that the object sending the event may be disposed between the time the system decides that they should run, and the time it actually runs them.

(*) The essential purpose of `IDisposable` is to allow an object to notify entities which are outside it but are acting on its behalf to the detriment of other entities, that they should no longer do so [e.g. to tell a file system that it should no longer grant an object exclusive access to a file].  Such action is referred to as "releasing resources".  The fact that someone holds the last surviving reference to an object may imply that no other thread can be using that object, but does not imply that no other thread is using any non-thread-safe entities whose resources need to be released.

Comment: So, it all depends on how Dispose was implemented. if implementation where not to leave instance in a 'non-functional' state, there would be no harm in calling Dispose in a event handler?

Comment: @Goran: It depends upon the exact object in question, but in general if the owner of an object intends to keep it until something happens, and an event from the object provides notification when it does, it should be safe to use that event to dispose the object.

Comment: I could make comparison to Task library. You create a task, you execute it, and after the task completed, a method that is passed to ContinueWith will be called. Can we dispose both of task objects (original Task and Task returned by ContinueWith) in this method? I do not want to go into debate whether it is necessary to dispose Task (I know the story about disposing the WaitHandle), I just need to know - can we?